# How Integrate between Autodesk forge and CRM 365?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, integration, autodesk-forge, dynamics-crm-365-v9

i want to integrate between auto-desk forge in CRM 365, to view and set data in CRM.

any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What data/capabilities are you looking to integrate? So I can make this answer more relevant to your needs.

Forge outputs data in the JSON format so you can then convert a compatible format (CSV etc.) for Dynamics. [Here's](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tokenflex&type=&language=) a couple of samples that export Forge data to CSV.

Alternatively try the MS Flow platform to automated workflow - we plan to release a custom Forge connector in the near future - stay tuned to our official blog for updates.

**UPDATE**

> Integrate Forge Viewer with Dynamics 365 to visualize models

Create a web app with Viewer to load the models then insert an `iframe` control to your 365 form linking to your web app - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/iframe-properties-legacy).

> save the design properties for example (name, code, color, length, width ....)

The design data would be extracted and available at [GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) once the model has been [translated](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) to any format.

Comment: thank you for response,

What I specifically want is show the view  from Forge in CRM
And save the design properties for example (name, code, color, length, width ....)

Comment: By `view` did you mean Forge Viewer to visualize the models? If so see the updated answer.

Comment: Dear thank you,
I'll try and tell you what has been done.

Comment: Dear Brian,
 I tried to apply your suggestion after my research on this topic Download the sample code from the relevant throttle site. So what is the right way to carry out my mission I am now confused and tired of my mission Can you give me a personal contact like mail?

Comment: Basically you will need to set up your Forge Viewer app on a server that can be accessed by your users and integrate the app by embedding in an iFrame on your Dynamics 365 - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/create-web-resources-iframe-mobile) for more details on the embedding front (if you have limited exposure to web dev I'd suggest to leave this to your developers). And you can send questions to our team mail @ forge.help at autodesk.com